# Variavel inválida

Tags: php

Estou com um problema por causa de uma variável inválida. Diz-me sempre que a variável `AlvaraAnexo` é inválida.

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("Select* From tb_trabalhador WHERE id = $id");



function apresentarAlvara ($id, $AlvaraAnexo) {
$href = 'MostrarAlvara.php?id='.$id.'&amp;documento='.$AlvaraAnexo;
$title = 'Clique para abrir documento';

$html = '
<p>
Visualizar documento Alvara: <a href="MostrarAlvara.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">Ver PDF  </a>
</p>';

return $html;
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar a mensagem de erro?

Comment: O seu `while` está aberto, falta `}`. Como chama a função? e como o @perdeu pediu, junte o erro que deu.

Comment: pq essa function está dentro de um while?

Comment: Edite a pergunta pra por mais detalhes, de preferência o código completo, senão não dá nem pra começar a ajudar. Procure editar de uma vez do que fazer várias edições, pois após 10 edições a pergunta pode virar wiki da comunidade.

Comment: @nano.galvao só cuidado quando fizer essas edições muito pequenas (ainda mais quando a pergunta já tiver sido editada), pois após 5 pessoas diferentes editarem a mesma, ela também vira wiki da comunidade. (a edição é bem-vinda, mas quando é muito nova a pergunta, compensa esperar um pouco, geralmente o autor a edita volta e meia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a definição da função está dentro do `while` será emitido o erro:
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare: apresentarAlvara`.

Primeiro vc deveria declarar a função no inicio ou em outro arquivo. Veja que na função vc tem a variavel `$exibia['id']` acredito que ela deve ser substituida por apenas `$id`, pois `$exibi` não é uma variavel global.

```
<?php
function apresentarAlvara ($id, $AlvaraAnexo) {
$href = 'MostrarAlvara.php?id='.$id.'&amp;documento='.$AlvaraAnexo;
$title = 'Clique para abrir documento';

$html = '
<p>
Visualizar documento Alvara: <a href="MostrarAlvara.php?id='.$id.'">Ver PDF  </a>
</p>';

return $html;
}


include("conectar.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("Select* From tb_trabalhador WHERE id = $id");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    apresentarAlvara($exibi['id'], $exibi['nome']);
}
```